# Cómo revisar MySQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

- Un sitio Wordpress fue hackeado, al tratar de loguearse daba error 403.
- Por cPanel se accedió a los archivos.
- Se eliminaron todos excepto wp-content y wp-config.php
- Se cambiaron nombres de usuarios (eran pocos), claves y esas cosas.
- Se configuró .htaccess restringiendo acceso a carpetas, renombrando el wp-admin
- Ahora sólo falta limpiar la base de datos.  Se corrió un plugin que eliminó varias cosas.
- El sitio se recuperó y aparentemente funciona bien, excepto porque tarda en cargarse.
- Los post (29) y páginas realmente son muy pequeños, casi no tienen imágenes.  Un sitio similar con más de 500 posts no tiene ese problema.
- La pregunta es; cómo limpiar la base de datos y cómo verificar que no haya código malicioso?
- Muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

pues aqui te dejo este [enlace](https://blog.baehost.com/como-limpiar-y-optimizar-la-base-de-datos-de-tu-wordpress/) en donde puedes correr algunas sentencias SQL desde phpMyAdmin para hacer lo que deseas.